# How can a sequence exist on the open interval $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If we have any sequence $\{x_n\}$ on $(0,1)$, for example, $x_n=n$, then doesn't the sequence not have any values on $(0,1)$, since it's an open interval and we can only use natural numbers for the n value? If it was closed then the example would be $x_0=0$ and $x_1=1$. I know this is wrong, I think I'm misunderstanding what it means for a sequence to exist on an interval...

Comment: If someone tells you to take a sequence on $(0,1)$, that means that you need to take a sequence for which each element already lives in $(0,1)$, such as, say, $x_n := \frac{1}{2}$, $x_n := \frac{1}{n}$, or some other sequence. What you tried to do, which is picking a sequence and then only considering the elements of that sequence that belong in $(0,1)$ when there are any, is not really the good approach to this.

Comment: Ohhh duh, makes sense. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A *sequence in the interval $(0,1)$* is a function which, for each input $n=1,2,3,...$, outputs a number $x_n \in (0,1)$.

As with many functions, the output value $x_n$ might be expressed as a formula in the quantity $n$.

For example $x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ is a sequence in the interval $(0,1)$, because $0 < \frac{1}{n+1} < 1$ for all $n=1,2,3,....$.

One nice thing about sequences is that, besides giving a formula for their values, one can often literally list their values out one-by-one. For the example $x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ we have
$$x_1 = \frac{1}{2}, \quad x_2 = \frac{1}{3}, \quad x_3 = \frac{1}{4}, \quad x_4 = \frac{1}{5}, ...
$$